# Multiple rand() functions repeat the same output despite seeding

Tags: c++

Despite seeding the rand() every time I call the two functions, they always repeat the same output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;



void test1(){
 srand(time(0));
 int i = rand()%10;
 cout << i << endl;
}
void test2(){
 srand(time(NULL));
 int l = rand()%10;
 cout << l << endl;
}

int main(){
  test1();
  test2();

 return 0;
}
```

output:
0
0

output 2:
4
4

output 3:
1
1

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `time(0)` returns the same value for up to a second so if your code takes less than a second to execute you'll probably seed with the same number every time

Comment: Usually `srand` is called only once by a program, shortly after the start of `main`.

Comment: The title is wrong. Should be "multiple `rand()` functions repeat the same output **because of** seeding".